# Twitter rest client showing the full length of url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter

I am trying to implement twitter rest client using twitter gem.

```
def tweetartist
    artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
    @twitter = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = '******'
      config.consumer_secret = '*******'
      config.access_token = current_user.oauth_token
      config.access_token_secret = current_user.oauth_secret
    end

    @twitter.update("Check out " + artist.name + " at *****! " + params[:link])

     if request.xhr?
        render :json => {
          :place => "Success"  }
    end
    return
  end
```

params[:link] = `http://localhost:3000/artists/17?refid=*****`

while the above works and the pre-populated tweet gets posted on the current_users wall, the link itself is the full length, instead of being the blueish color and shortened to 23 characters according to Twitter. Is that the expect behavior or am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It's the `localhost` part -- twitter leaves those alone.  If you really want to test how it will look, you can use a localhost/proxy.  http://localtest.me:3000 is the same as http://localhost:3000